# Emitting socket.io event from Sails.JS and handling it on server using Sails.JS skeleton

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I have a problem in understanding the concept of sending socket.io events from Sails.js client side controller and handling them in server-side controllers. First of all, I have downloaded the SailsJS project skeleton using npm and the structure as follows:

Project:

```
api
--adapters
--controllers
----server_userController.js
--models
--polices
--services

assets
--[styles, views, images, bower_components, and etc]
--js
----controllers
------userController.js
----app.js
----sails.io.js
----socket.io.js
config
node_modules
views
```

I wrote the following in "assets/js/controllers/server_userController.js":

```
socket.emit('getUser', {
    _id: 10
});
```

Now, how to specify which server-side controller is responsible for handling this event, and how? I want this event to be received in "api/controllers/server_userController.js". So, something like this will be in the controller:

```
module.exports = {
  //Handling socket request here
  //Emitting socket request
};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is run a Sails controller action via sockets, then you don't need to `emit` anything at all.  Part of Sails' charm is that it can route regular, HTTP-style requests over sockets.  So if you have a controller `/api/controllers/FooController.js` like:

```
module.exports = {

    bar: function (req, res) {

        // Note, you can check whether this was a socket request
        // with req.isSocket, and if so access the connecting
        // socket with req.socket

        res.json({"message": "Hello!"});

    }

}
```

and you include the bundled `sails.io.js` file in your client-side app, then you can access that action via:

```
socket.get('/foo/bar', function(data) {
    // data will contain {message:"hello"}
}
```

*Note: if you're using the newer version of `sails.io.js` that is included with Sails v0.10.x, it's `io.socket.get`.*

If you really want to catch socket events on the server, the best place to register them is in your `/config/socket.js` file, in the `onConnect` method:

```
onConnect: function (socket, session) {

    socket.on('some_event', function(data) {
        // handle event here
    });

}
```

This is better than putting the event handlers in a controller, because any time that controller action ran it would bind the event again, and you'd see the callback being run multiple times.

Comment: I was really confused and I was desperately looking for the second approach in emitting and receiving socket events. Using the controller gave me the feeling that I'm using REST API. Unfortunately, that is because sails documentation is not sufficient enough. Thanks a lot. The second method works fine.

Comment: Yes, the idea is to be able to use a REST API over sockets just like you would with HTTP.  See the [sailsChat](https://github.com/balderdashy/sailschat) app for an example.

Answer (score 3):

Be sure to read the [SailsJS v0.11 Migration Guide](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/master/0.11-migration-guide.md) before using onConnect. This has now been deprecated.